# How to install Plotly in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I am having a trouble installing the plotly package in my Jupyter notebook.
I tried the method in the official website and it show as below:

```
$ pip install plotly==5.7.0
```

And it turned out to be:

```
File "<ipython-input-37-cd34544b05a0>", line 1
$ pip install plotly==5.7.0
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried:

```
!pip install plotly
```

And it is said:

```
Collecting plotly
 Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/plotly/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/plotly/
```

Can anyone help or share with me the instructions?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your proxy. You need to set the verify == False somewhere. Normally via CMD is much easier. However you can try using this on jupyter

```
!pip install plotly config --global http.sslVerify false
```

As stated in my answear below. If the line doesn't work, you have a bigger problem which is your proxy. After setting your proxy, please use this line

```
!pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org plotly
```

Comment: In general, I'd encourgae not suggesting use of the exclamation point with `pip install`. (Same holds for `conda install`.) You should now be using the modern magics that have been added `%pip install` or `%conda install` when running an installation from in a cell inside the notebook, for those unfamiliar see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez). But **maybe this is a special case** where you know you need the exclamation point?

Comment: Hi Mina. I tried to use your code, however, the result turned out to be the same:
Collecting plotly
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/plotly/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/plotly/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1045)'))) - skipping

Maybe I am missing some other steps?

Comment: is this a personal pc or a company pc? If the is a personal pc, you need to handle your proxy via adding the path. If this is a company pc, you need to add your password to your proxy (please contact your IT). If this first step is done, please use the following line that I will add to my answear

Comment: Thank you! I used your second line of codes and it turned out to be workable. You saved my life.

Comment: Glad I have helped. Unfortunately, proxy problems are very common and there is no one solution. Very happy to have found a solution this fast